# Issue with ConnectionService PhoneAccount registering in android

Tags: android, twilio, incoming-call, voip-android

I am trying to use `Twilio` for video calling application, one end is web and another end is android. Using Firebase to trigger push notification from web to android. I need to convert the push notification as  Incoming call screen in android application, to do that I have used `ConnectionService` which is documented as available from API 23. I have registered `PhoneAccount` as below:

```
TelecomManager tm = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE); 
PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(
                new ComponentName(this.getApplicationContext(), MyConnectionService.class),
                "AppName");
PhoneAccount phoneAccount = PhoneAccount.builder(phoneAccountHandle, "AppName")
    .setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CONNECTION_MANAGER).build();
    tm.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);
```

I registered PhoneAccount for first time with

```
PhoneAccount phoneAccount = PhoneAccount.builder(phoneAccountHandle, "AppName")
  .setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED).build();
```

which will work only on API 26, Later I changed it to

```
PhoneAccount phoneAccount = PhoneAccount.builder(phoneAccountHandle, "AppName")
.setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CONNECTION_MANAGER).build();
```

Later one worked as expected in API 26 but on lower versions, it gave an exception

> java.lang.SecurityException: This PhoneAccountHandle is not registered for this user!

can anybody help with this issue?

Comment: did you find any solution? i am having the same issue, it was working for some time and then again give the same error

Comment: Same issue here.....I don't find solutions anywhere. It is working with some phones, I have that weird message in others. Even after theorically "activating" the account by doing Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.server.telecom","com.android.server.telecom.settings.EnableAccountPreferenceActivity"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(intent);